# OR i xpath such based on nth element and attribute value

Tags: xpath

I have two docs as below:

```
<td class="first">
   <td>...</td>
    .
    .
   <td>Thank You</td>
</td>


<td class="first">
   <td>...</td>
    .
    .
   <td "id=description">Thank You</td>
</td>
```

Now I need a single XPATH that would return me the "Thank you" for both docs. The point is the td element may have the id attribute(id=description) but some times it may not whence it is the 4th child in that case.

Need an Xpath query that will serve both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore presence/absence of `id` attribute and just use the position of target `td` element:

```
//tr[@class="first"]/td[position()=last()]/text()
```

Above `XPath` expression will match the last `td` in table row and return `"Thank You"` in both cases. You can also specify the exact position as `td[position()=4]`